# How do I set up auto git push every 10 minutes from my client's server?

Tags: git, ssh, cron

I'm about to wrap up a project with a client. I'm using github to store all of the files. He is naturally going to be making updates via the CMS, uploading new images, etc after I am off the project.

I am afraid that six months or a year from now if something breaks we will be in a bad place because it will be a full year or so of changes without any git commits (Again, this is a client. I don't expect him to SSH in and run git commands.) I'm trying to set up a crontab job that will run hourly that will add everything, commit it, and push it to github. The problem I am running into is that it asks for my username and password and fails. How can I set it up so that my client's server can push changes to the github repo without having to compromise my security?

Here is what I have so far.

```
0 * * * * cd ~/clientswebsite.com/; git add -u; git commit -m "Cron job"; git push --verbose > log.txt
```

Comment: Won't this fail if the client removes or renames a file? Not sure there's a good way to do this without wiring git to webdav or something.

Comment: That's what the -u param is for in git add. No? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: `-u` doesn't add new files. Use `-A`. Also remember to handle the case when there are no changes (commit should fail by default then).

Comment: why not use `git add *`, simply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but essentially, you have to start using SSH key authentication instead of username/password authentication.

The options depend on what, precisely, you'd like to identify using the key.  For your case I'd say it's either Deploy Key (which is bound to a machine) or a Machine User (which is bound to a specific user account, possibly across machines).

See this GitHub article for the details:  https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

Comment: Thank you so much. After reading this article and several others that it links to I figured it out :D